# You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API Issue

Tags: api, limit, quota

We are getting this error in console:

> You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did
>   not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an
>   active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account  For more
>   information on usage limits and the Google Maps JavaScript API
>   services please see:
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage"

We already have a billing account for Google Locations API and we are using a Key already.
This account is operational for last 4 years. Suddenly, this issue pops up today.
Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether all settings are correct (the proper key is used, the developer console does not show any problems with your limits,....)?

Comment: Thanks for your response. We are using the same account and code for last few years. Key is Ok. Account is linked to billing information already. There must be some change at Google end as per my understanding.

Comment: @sparonline this is a known issue in the Google APIs related to the billing which i think is a bug, happened to me once.
Also before doing following steps you need to disable all the APIs from google console.
You need to remove the linked billing account and add again the billing account and then disable and enable the APIs

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems to be related to billing currency. It seems INR no longer is supported as currency for Google maps API. We are making the required changes. Will update if this works.